# Foreach loop returning only the last result

Tags: php

I have results returned from DB, which I want to loop trough and use switch on them to kind of sort them by type to afterwards echo them out, but it's returning only the last DB entry.

```
<?php

require_once 'classes/Database.php';
require_once 'classes/products/Product.php';
require_once 'classes/products/Book.php';
require_once 'classes/products/DVD.php';
require_once 'classes/products/Furniture.php';

$db = new Database;

$productList = $db->query('SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY created_at DESC');
$results = $db->resultSet();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    switch ($result->type) {
        case 'book':
            $product = new Book($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, $result->size);
            break;
        case 'dvd':
            $product = new DVD($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, $result->size);
            break;
        case 'furniture':
            $product = new Furniture($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, array($result->size));
            break;
    }
}

$products[] = $product;

?>
```

// And below you can see the part where I try to output the data, but only the last result is returned.

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
                <p class="item">SKU: <?php echo $product->id; ?></p>
                <p class="item">Name: <?php echo $product->name; ?></p>
                <p class="item">Price: <?php echo $product->price; ?></p>
                <p class="item">Size: <?php echo $product->formatSize(); ?></p>
 <?php endforeach;?>
```

I'd like to see all results returned. If I echo for example just name from switch cases, it returns what I need,  but seems like the lower loop isnt working properly.

Comment: You keep overwriting it, instead of appending it.Move `$products[] = $product;` inside the loop. Remember to define it before using it!

Comment: You need to move `$products[] = $product;` inside the loop

Comment: look at your code `where` you append your element to the array.....

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't notice this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from people in the comments. I had to simply move:

`$products[] = $product;` inside my loop.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwritting $product on your switch case , try to something like this , it should work :

```
$x = -1;
foreach ($results as $result) {
$x++;
switch ($result->type) {
    case 'book':
        $product[$x] = new Book($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, $result->size);
        break;
    case 'dvd':
        $product[$x] = new DVD($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, $result->size);
        break;
    case 'furniture':
        $product[$x] = new Furniture($result->id, $result->name, $result->price, array($result->size));
        break;
        }
}
```